# adding another CALayer atop of a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer

Tags: ios, avfoundation, swift4

I'm trying to add another later atop of a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer. I have tried adding it above the preview layer, in the viewdidload and a few other things. still no joy. Anyone have any ideas?

```
 func configureCaptureSession() {
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo

    let deviceDiscoverySession = 
AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInDualCamera], 
mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .unspecified)

    for device in deviceDiscoverySession.devices {
        if device.position == .back {
            rearCam = device
        } else if device.position == .front {
            frontCam = device
        }
    }
currentDevice = rearCam
    guard let captureDeviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: 
currentDevice) else {
        return
    }
    wheelOverlay.image = UIImage(named: "wheel")
    wheelOverlayLayer.contents = wheelOverlay
    stillPhotoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()

    captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)

    captureSession.addOutput(stillPhotoOutput)
    view.layer.addSublayer(wheelOverlayLayer)

    cameraPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: 
captureSession)
    view.layer.insertSublayer(cameraPreviewLayer!, below: 
wheelOverlayLayer)
    cameraPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = 
AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    cameraPreviewLayer?.frame = view.layer.frame
    print("Capture session setup")
   // view.layer.addSublayer(wheelOverlayLayer)
   // view.layer.insertSublayer(wheelOverlayLayer, above: 
cameraPreviewLayer)
    captureSession.startRunning()


}
```

Comment: You have to check the frames of both cameraPreviewLayer and wheelOverlayLayer after adding them to the view layer

Comment: What do you mean by check them? I’m a little bit confused sorry

Comment: Print out to see whether the layer has a valid size

Comment: I just added a separate uiview on top of camera preview uiview.